# What is the process name of Time Machine timeline

Tags: time-machine, command-line, macos

What is the process name of Time Machine timeline?

[image: Picture of Apple Time Machine timeline]

I would like to write a script that looks up when it is running so that I can  disable my windows manager ([Kwm](https://github.com/koekeishiya/kwm)) when I enter the timeline.

Answer (score 1):

To view process,  in Terminal:
`top -o cpu`
Top will list all your current processes and organizing by CPU load makes it a breeze to find the desired PID

Comment: Thanks! I was able to figure out that Time Machine processes are `backups` and `backups-helper`. It looks like those processes are always running in the background, though. I am looking for the process that creates the Timeline interface when you go to restore a previous backup.

Comment: I would not at all be surprised if it turns out to be the Finder that is responsible for that display. My main evidence for believing it is, is circumstantial: Witness the smooth transition as you enter and leave Time Machine. (Edit: I noticed just now that this is an old question and answer. Odd that no one else has made the same guess.)

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen Finder is the interface for Time Machine. If you turned off window animation and transparency, I'm certain you wouldn't see that pretty display.